# c++ delete one biggest value and zeroes from array

Tags: c++, arrays

i have a double array with 10 values inside, firstly my function should find and delete biggest value from array if this value is only one time in array, and secondly delete zero values from array. At this point we can not use any vectors to solve this out.

```
void calculations(double first[], int& n)
{
    int k = 0;
    double max1= first[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (first[i] > max1)
        {
            max1 = first[i];
        }
            if (first[i] == max1)
            {
            k++;
            }
            if (k < 2)
            {
                for (int i = max1; i < n - 1; i++)
                {
                first[i] = first[i + 1];
                n--;
                }
            }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (first[i] == 0)
        {
            first[i] = first[i + 1];
            n--;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << first[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: you cannot remove elements from c-style arrays. What do you mean with "delete elements from the array" ?

Comment: ...and more importantly: What is your question?

Comment: Please read [tour] then [ask] then [mcve] then edit your post to be a question.

Comment: after deleted biggest value and zero values array should ecome smaller

Comment: Use `std::vector`.  The `std::vector` has an [`erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) method that actually removes an element.  See also `std::array`.

Comment: @tobi303 What do you mean by "you can't"? Shift all elements with higher index to the left and remember, that size of array is smaller now. Do you think `std::vector` does something different, then `erase`?

Comment: Possible duplicate *posts*, [search for "StackOverflow C++ (remove OR delete) array element"](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+c%2B%2B+%28remove+OR+delete%29+array+element&nfpr=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjw5qyMrvrVAhUqrFQKHcyGCP8QvgUIJigB&biw=1920&bih=1103)

Comment: @SemyonBurov thats not the only strategy I can think of to remove elements from an array.

Comment: @SemyonBurov and with "you can't" I literally mean "you can't". Even if you shift the values, the elements are still there, while a vector may easily shrink its capacity after removing elements

Comment: memcpy from the current array into a smaller one with the values removed.  It's icky, but it doesn't require any vector work.  This smells like a school assignment.

Comment: @tobi303 By reallocating memory and copying all other elements? Of course `vector` can do it, but I cant say its "easily"

Comment: @barkman345 What if there is only 1 value in the array?  How do you "delete" this value since it is the largest and there is only one of them?  See how this whole thing of using static arrays falls apart when cases like this occur?  Second, you say you can't use `std::vector`, but you didn't indicate whether you couldn't use the algorithm functions.  `std::remove()` works on an array just fine, and you could have used that to "remove" the zeros from the array, i.e. `double* ptr = std::remove(first, first + n, 0);` and then the "new size" of the array is `std::distance(first, ptr);`

Answer (score 0):

In order to *remove* an element from an array, you need to move all the remaining elements "up" by one, such that `array[i] = array[i+1];`

Another alternative is to indicate that the array slot is available for reuse.

See `std::vector::erase` and `std::array`.

Answer (score 0):

That reads a lot like a programming course assignment? Anyway, I'd do a two pass approach:

1st pass has two tasks:

1. Find the biggest element and remember it; also make sure it's only there once.
2. Count the number of zeroes.

In code:

```
if (n == 0)
    return; //just to be safe

size_t max_value = first[0];
bool max_value_is_unique = true;
size_t zeroes = first[0] == 0 ? 1 : 0;
//start at 1, since we already looked at first[0] above!
for (size_t i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    //oh, it's a 0; count it!
    if (first[i] == 0)
        zeroes++;

    //check if this is equal to or bigger than current maximum
    if (first[i] == max_value)
        max_value_is_unique = false;
    else if (first[i] > max_value) {
        max_value = first[i];
        max_value_is_unique = true;
    }
}
```

Optimization:
If there is no unique biggest element AND the number of zeroes is 0, return:

```
if (zeroes == 0 && !max_value_is_unique)
    return;
```

Else, run the 2nd pass:

This one will just move entries from the right to your current position.
Once we hit a 0 or the maximum value, the move distance is increased since we want to skip that value.

```
//move all entries some distance "to the left"
int distance = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < n - distance; /* no increment! */) {
    bool might_inc = true;
    //we skip the current value in case it's a zero or the maximum value
    if ((max_value_is_unique && first[i] == max_value) || first[i] == 0)
        distance++;

    if (distance > 0) {
        if (i + distance < n) {
            //we might reach out of the array here, so this line guarded
            first[i] = first[i + distance];
            //since we just copied some value to the current `i`, we need to take a look at that `i` it again - it might be 0 or the maximum value
            might_inc = false;
        } else
            //if we would reach out of the array, write 0
            first[i] = 0;
     }

     if (might_inc)
         i++;
}

//you didn't specify it, so I'll just set the remaining entries to 0
for (int i = n - distance; i < n; ++i) {
    first[i] = 0;
}
```

I didn't check corner cases like all zeroes, but I think it should work.
Could be faster in case you know there are X trailing zeroes, and instead of copying & then checking the copied value, you could check the value before copying. But well, as I said, it looks like a exercise, the length is 10, so well, that should be fine ;-)

If you don't know `size_t`, that's a fancy datatype which will always be big enough to address your whole memory. **In this code**, you can most likely just write `unsigned int` or `int` instead. But **I** believe `size_t` to be the better style and it's a good practice to rigorously use it where appropriate.

Comment: for some reason this code is not printing any results

Comment: It was just a quick write down and I didn't bother testing it... so maybe there are mistakes, but it should convey the general idea (I hope).
And if you look really close you'll find I omitted a print loop... Thought you should be able to do that? ;)

Answer (score 0):

your code is totally wrong

your first for loop should only used to find the maximum value and counts, every time you find a bigger value, you need to reset your counter, k

then use another for loop to remove values, i+1 can go out of boundary and n-- would prevent you traversing the whole array

your for loop used to to delete values is also wrong, you should have two number to indicates the index of keeping and probing.

for example, to remove 0 from [1,0,0,4], your code would end with [1,0,4,4] and change size to 2

Answer (score 0):

Your removing is inside of searching - its wrong

You dont actually need to count maximums

You cant compare floating point values such as `float`, `double` and `long double` by simple `==`. You need to measure difference between them and if its less than some small value of tolerance consider them equal.

So... try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>

void remove_all(double* array, std::size_t& size, double val) {
    double eps = 1e-9; 
    std::size_t k = 0, tail = 0;
    while (k + tail < size) {
        if (std::fabs(array[k + tail] - val) < eps) // correct floating point numbers equality compare
            ++tail;
        else {
            array[k] = array[k + tail];
            ++k;
        }
    }
    size -= tail;
}

void remove_max_and_zeros(double* array, std::size_t& size) {
    //-- find max element in array --
    double maxVal = array[0];
    for (std::size_t k = 0; k < size; ++k) 
        if (maxVal < array[k])
            maxVal = array[k];
    //-- remove max element from array --
    remove_all(array, size, maxVal);
    //-- remove zeros from array --
    remove_all(array, size, 0.0);
}

int main()
{
    const std::size_t maxSize = 10;
    double arr[maxSize] = { 1.1, 1.3, 0.0, 2.5, 0.0, -5.8, 2.5, 0.0, 0.0001, 0.0 };
    std::size_t size = maxSize;

    for (std::size_t k = 0; k < size; ++k)
        std::cout << arr[k] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    remove_max_and_zeros(arr, size);

    for (std::size_t k = 0; k < size; ++k)
        std::cout << arr[k] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```